# How to find out which tables were change after a specified time

Tags: sql, oracle

I am looking for a SQL statement that can show me all the tables that were changed after a specified time. Google gave me

```
SELECT * FROM all_tab_modifications;

select tab.owner as table_schema,
       tab.table_name,
       obj.last_ddl_time as last_modify
from all_tables tab
join all_objects obj on tab.owner = obj.owner
     and tab.table_name = obj.object_name
where tab.owner not in ('ANONYMOUS','CTXSYS','DBSNMP','EXFSYS', 'LBACSYS',
     'MDSYS', 'MGMT_VIEW','OLAPSYS','OWBSYS','ORDPLUGINS', 'ORDSYS','OUTLN',
     'SI_INFORMTN_SCHEMA','SYS','SYSMAN','SYSTEM','TSMSYS','WK_TEST',
     'WKSYS','WKPROXY','WMSYS','XDB','APEX_040000','APEX_PUBLIC_USER','DIP',
     'FLOWS_30000','FLOWS_FILES','MDDATA', 'ORACLE_OCM', 'XS$NULL',
     'SPATIAL_CSW_ADMIN_USR', 'SPATIAL_WFS_ADMIN_USR', 'PUBLIC')
      and obj.last_ddl_time > (current_date - INTERVAL '60' DAY)
order by last_modify desc;
```

However, neither of these picks up the change I made in Oracle E-Business Suite to move an asset. In fact they show no changes for today. With `all_tab_modifications` this might relate to the fact that it only shows changes after the last running of statistics, but this makes it useless since running statistics on all tables would be difficult. Is there any way of doing this? I would like to find out which tables were changed during the asset move.

Comment: I believe those queries only show structural modifications to tables (i.e. DDL), not data changes (i.e. DML).

Comment: does this help ? https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1590655700346557237

Comment: With auditing you would need to know which tables to audit, so that won't work.

Comment: Have you got LogMiner configured for use? See [Poor Man's Auditing](http://www.nocoug.org/download/2008-05/LogMiner4.pdf). But it's like auditing in that you need to set it up beforehand.

Comment: No LogMiner no.